# Input information to database, display it with PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a form where I enter text, then it goes to the database and after I want it to be immediately displayed on the same page. I enter the info and submit it, page reloads and nothing appears in database or page. Any ideas maybe?

Saving part:

```
if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
                $Vardas = $_POST['vardas'];
                $Epastas = $_POST['epastas'];
                $Kam = $_POST['kam'];
                $Zinute = $_POST['zinute'];
                $Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                /*$IP = $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR];*/
                }
//else {die ("Neuzpildyta forma");}
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (vardas, epastas, kam, data, zinute) 
VALUES ('$Vardas', '$Epastas','$Kam', '$Date', '$Zinute')";
//if (mysqli_query($dbc, $sql)) echo "Įrašyta";
//else die ("Klaida įrašant:" .mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Form:

```
    <form method='post' action="">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                <label for="vardas" class="control-label">Siuntėjo vardas:</label>
                                <input name='vardas' type='text' class="form-control input-sm">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                 <label for="epastas" class="control-label">Siuntėjo e-paštas:</label>
                                 <input name='epastas' id="epastas" type='email' class="form-control input-sm">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                 <label for="kam" class="control-label">Kam skirta:</label>
                                 <input name='kam' type='text' class="form-control input-sm">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                 <label for="zinute" class="control-label">Žinutė:</label>
                                 <textarea name='zinute' class="form-control input-sm"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
                                 <input type='submit' name='ok' value='siųsti' class="btnbtn-default">
                            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You have your database query execution commented out.

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.**

Comment: I presume you know it's commented out?

Comment: Yes, I am very new to php and copied some of the code from youtube video and am learning this way. Thank You all, now I know what that means! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing your `$mysqli` connection. Your code is also very susceptible to mysql injection so here is my recommendation.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database_name");

if(isset($_POST['ok'])){
    $Vardas = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['vardas']);
    $Epastas = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['epastas']);
    $Kam = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['kam']);
    $Zinute = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['zinute']);
    $Date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $my_insert_query = "INSERT INTO table1 (vardas, epastas, kam, data, zinute)
    VALUES ('$Vardas', '$Epastas','$Kam', '$Date', '$Zinute')";

    $insert = $mysqli->query($my_insert_query);
    if($insert){
        echo "Success!";
    }else{
        echo "error" . $mysqli->error;
    }
}
```

The code above should work and prevent any sql injection.